# Remove first words from file

Tags: c, tcp, tcpclient

sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm kind of inexperienced with C. I'm trying to create a simple TCP client/server connection. This is how it works: the server stores several files, including .txt and .jpg. When the client wants one of them, he sends the name of the file to the server, reading and writing it to a certain location.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that the server's response is "RES *status size data*" . I'm only interested in the *data* to create the new file, but I'm not being able to deny the writing of RES *status size* into the output file. I tried to use strtok but am getting a segfault because of it, dunno why. This is the section of code where I receive the response from the server and start writing it to a new file *fp*.

```
while(success == 0)
    {
        while(f_block_sz = recvfrom(fd2, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr2, &addrlen))
        {


            if(f_block_sz < 0)
            {
                printf("Receive file error.\n");
                break;
            }
            int write_sz = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), f_block_sz, fp);
            if(write_sz < f_block_sz)
            {
                printf("File write failed.\n");
                break;
            }
            bzero(buffer, LENGTH);
        }

        printf("ok!\n");
        success = 1;
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

I don't even know what's best. Should I remove those "useless" words before writing to the newfile, or should I edit the file after it's finished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure but i just thought if your "RES status size" is of fixed size, say 'x' bytes then while writing to the output file just skip x bytes of received data...

```
int write_sz = fwrite(buffer + x, sizeof(char), f_block_sz, fp);
```

I am not sure this is good practice or even correct, i just gave in my thought.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks! Didn't even think of that. Unfortunately size can be anything from 1 to something like 23000. Could there be a way to read how many characters until the 3rd " "?

Comment: Exactly. I was now thinking of doing something like this:
    `for(g=1; ; g++){
                    fscanf(fp+7,"%c",&c);
                    if(c==' ')
                        return g;
                    else fp++;
                }`

It's probably wrong, but I think you get the idea. I'd like to start checking the string after "RES ok", and when I got to a "space" I would have the beginning of data. I would then replace the x with the value of g. Am I thinking this right?

Comment: well, in-case if the size is a variable the i think u need to copy the received buffer to another buffer skipping all the characters until the 3rd " "(space), then write the buffer to output file.

Comment: yap... as far as i can see or think its you are thinking it correctly, but just hang on, someone might give a better answer. i too am a kind of new to c.